# Are modes like CBC, OFB, CFB subject to chosen plaintext attacks?

Tags: modes-of-operation, chosen-plaintext-attack

I haven't found much info on the internet about the weakness of modes to chosen plaintext attacks, but from what I understand of them, there seem to be some trivial attacks, so I'm a bit confused.
For example, let's encrypt 2 blocks of plaintext with value 0 with CBC:

C0=Ek(P0+IV)=Ek(IV)

C1=Ek(P1+C0)=Ek(Ek(IV))

But then we have a double encryption of IV, which should be subject to a Meet in the Middle attack.
Is there something wrong with my reasoning or are chaining modes of operation inherently weak against chosen plaintext attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)), [OFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_feedback_(OFB)), [CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_(CFB)), [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) modes resist chosen plaintext attack, if the underlying block cipher is secure, and the [Initialization Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) is uniformly random and unpredictable, and the total amount of blocks stays below $\sqrt{\|B\|}\,\epsilon^{-2}$ blocks, where $\|B\|$ is the size of the block space and $\epsilon$ is the desired residual probability of success of adversaries.

Getting $\mathsf{IV}$, $E_K(\mathsf{IV})$ and $E_K(E_K(\mathsf{IV}))$, as we can have with CBC mode under chosen plaintext attack, does not allow to mount a [Meet in the Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) attack. Argument: such attacks require that the *key* can be divided into segments that allow a meaningful calculation, and here $K$ remains a single entity.